# Flat JSON unflatten to hierarchy with multiple parents as String

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, graph

I am trying to unflatten some json-data. If i use my test data like following everything works fine!

```js
var data = [
  { "title": 1, "parentids": [0] }, 
  { "title": 2, "parentids": [1] },
  { "title": 3, "parentids": [1] },
  { "title": 4, "parentids": [2, 3] },
];
```

So if i use my function for this dataset i receive the following structure and that is actually what I want.

```
[
 {
  "title": 0,
  "parentids": [],
  "children": [
   {
    "title": 1,
    "parentids": [
     0
    ],
    "children": [
     {
      "title": 2,
      "parentids": [
       1
      ],
      "children": [
       {
        "title": 4,
        "parentids": [
         2,
         3
        ],
        "children": []
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "title": 3,
      "parentids": [
       1
      ],
      "children": [
       {
        "title": 4,
        "parentids": [
         2,
         3
        ],
        "children": []
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

BUT! My data has changed.And unfortunately my title and my parentids are now string values

```
var data = [
  { "title": "any", "parentids": [""] },
  { "title": "culture", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "building", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "museum", "parentids": ["culture", "building"] },
];
```

I really tried a lot to change and edit my exisiting code, but it wont work...either there is no output or the hierarchy is not like expected.Here is my actual function, which works for the first dataset. How could i change it, that it will work for string parentids;

```js
function unflatten(arr) {
  var node,
    graph = [], 
    mapped = [];

  // First map the nodes of the array to an object
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    node = arr[i];
    mapped[node.title] = node;
    mapped[node.title]['children'] = [];
  }

  // 2. assign children:
  mapped.forEach(function (node) {  
     // Add as child to each of the parents 
    node.parentids.forEach(function (parentid) {
      if (mapped[parentid]) {
        mapped[parentid]['children'].push(node);
      } else {
        // If parent does not exist as node, create it at the root level,
        // and add it to first level elements array.
        graph.push(mapped[parentid] = {
          title: parentid,   //name in this case its 0
          parentids: [],
          children: [node]

        });
      }
    });
  });
  return graph;

};

var graph = unflatten(types);

console.log(JSON.stringify(graph, null, 4));
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + (JSON.stringify(graph, null, " "))
```

Im not sure but i think the 2nd part with "if (mapped[parentid]" causes the issue? Because I am using now strings instead of integers? I really dont know how to continue... I appreciate any kind of hint or solution! 
Thanks in advance and have a nice day/week

Comment: your approach is wrong cause when parentids array is empty that means that object must be in the root level. check the length of parentids if has do the foreach thing without any condition. else add that element to root.

Comment: @Eldar with your hint I was able to manage it by my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this solution:

```js
var data = [
  { "title": "any", "parentids": [] },
  { "title": "culture", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "building", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "museum", "parentids": ["culture", "building"] },
]

// For each object in data, assign a children property.
data.forEach(o => o.children = [])

// For each object in data, assign a key/object pair using the title e.g
// { 
//   culture: { "title": "culture", "parentids": ["any"] }} 
//   ... 
// }
const map = data.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.title] = o, a), {})

// For each object in data, and for each parentid in that object,
// push this object to the object where the given parentid === ID
data.forEach(o => o.parentids.forEach(id => map[id] && map[id].children.push(o)))

// Filter the data object to only root elements (where there are no parentids)
const output = data.filter(e => !e.parentids.length)

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hey Kobe thanks it works! I will use it now because time is running, even if i dont understand it 100% so far... Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mikesh What don't you understand? I'll try my best to explain what is happening  

Comment: I was so happy that it worked, I didnt dive deeper into it. After i figured out my own solution ( Iam still learning so i did not just want to use ur code) I had a look into it and yes I gues your code is way better than mine, so I will use it. Thanks =)

Comment: I mean do you want me to explain my code? Or do you already understand how it works? @Mikesh

Comment: If you could explain the code, this would help me a lot i think! Thanks

Comment: @Mikesh I have added comments. Let me know if you still don't understand how it works.

Comment: @Kobe I like your solution because its concise. I need help with a similar flat data structure that needs to be converted into nested objects for a tree layout. The script I used reduces the data to unique children. In my use case I have children with duplicate parents...they need to show in the tree layout

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i ended up with

```js
var types1 = [
  { "title": "any", "parentids": [] },
  { "title": "culture", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "building", "parentids": ["any"] },
  { "title": "museum", "parentids": ["culture", "building"] },
];


function unflatten(arr) {
  var node,
    graph = [], 
    mapped = {};

  // First map the nodes of the array to an object -> create a hash table.
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    node = arr[i];

    mapped[node.title] = node;
    mapped[node.title]['children'] = [];
  }

  // 2. assign children:
  for (var index in mapped) {  
    if (mapped[index].parentids.length) {
      mapped[index].parentids.forEach(function (parentid) {
        mapped[parentid]['children'].push(mapped[index]);
      });
    } else {
      graph.push(mapped[index] = {
        title: mapped[index].parentids, 
        parentids: [],
        children: [mapped[index]]

      });
    }

  };
  return graph;

};

var graph = unflatten(types1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(graph, null, 4));
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + (JSON.stringify(graph, null, " "))
```